# Error: Opening the cache

Tags: error-handling

Recently I have been getting an error of opening cache its saying that it cannot open /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.gooogle.com_linux__chrome__deb...
The detailed one is in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TMrG.png) 
Could anyone please help to remove the error. 
I have tried by removing those lists directory and then running apt update, but it didn't work.